# How to Convert DataTable to Generic List in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to convert C# DataTable to Generic Collection List

```
DataTable Columns Respectively

 1. EmpId  (this is Int DataType)
 2. EmpName   (this is varchar DataType)
 3. EmpAddress  (this is varchar DataType)
 4. EmpPhone  (this is varchar DataType)
 5. Status   (this is Boolean DataType)
 6. EmpRelationKey (this is int DataType)
```

so my DataTable Contains Values for above fields. here i need to assign this value into my list

My List Variables Respectively

```
class Employee
{
protected int EmpId  ;
protected string EmpName =String.Empty;
protected string EmpAddress  = String.Empty;
protected string EmpPhone  = String.Empty;
protected bool Status ;
protected int EmpRelationKey ;
}

Declaring List
List<Employee> Emp= new List<Employee>
```

so now i need to assign DataTable values to this List. the code should be very professional.

i have tried this method

```
List<Employee>employees = new List<Employee>();  

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)  
{  
   employees.Add(new Employee  
   {  
   EmpId  = Convert.ToInt32(row["EmpId"]), 
   EmpName = row["EmpName"].ToString() ,
   EmpAddress =   row["EmpName"].ToString(),
   Emphone =   row["EmpPhone"].ToString(),
   Status = Convert.toBoolean(row["Status"])
   });  
}
```

but i don't want to mention column names , is there  any other ways to assign values without mentioning each and every column name from DataTable

Comment: reflection............

Comment: how to use that or apply to this

Comment: can you please help me out to solve this and post that code for reference

Comment: but my list is user defined type

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
using System.Reflection;
```

Then,

```
public static List<T> BindList<T>(DataTable dt)
{
    // Example 1:
    // Get private fields + non properties
    //var fields = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    // Example 2: Your case
    // Get all public fields
    var fields = typeof(T).GetFields();

    List<T> lst = new List<T>();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        // Create the object of T
        var ob = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        foreach (var fieldInfo in fields)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                // Matching the columns with fields
                if (fieldInfo.Name == dc.ColumnName)
                {
                    // Get the value from the datatable cell
                    object value = dr[dc.ColumnName];

                    // Set the value into the object
                    fieldInfo.SetValue(ob, value);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        lst.Add(ob);
    }

    return lst;
}
```

Example of usage:

```
DataTable dt1 = SqlHelper.GetTable("select * from employee;");
List<Employee> employees = BindList<Employee>(dt1);

DataTable dt2 = SqlHelper.GetTable("select * from membership;");
List<Membership> lstMembership = BindList<Membership>(dt2);

DataTable dt3 = SqlHelper.GetTable("select * from car order by name;");
List<Car> lstCar = BindList<Car>(dt3);
```

=====================

## **Extended Version**

Above example assume that the data holds inside the DataTable has the same **data type** as your **Class object**'s fields.

What if the data is not same as your class object's fields?

Such as **null**?

So, you might want to extend the method to take care just in case both data type are not the same.

```
public static List<T> BindList<T>(DataTable dt)
{
    // Example 1:
    // Get private fields + non properties
    //var fields = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    // Example 2: Your case
    // Get all public fields
    var fields = typeof(T).GetFields();

    List<T> lst = new List<T>();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        // Create the object of T
        var ob = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        foreach (var fieldInfo in fields)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                // Matching the columns with fields
                if (fieldInfo.Name == dc.ColumnName)
                {
                    Type type = fieldInfo.FieldType;

                    // Get the value from the datatable cell
                    object value = GetValue(dr[dc.ColumnName], type);

                    // Set the value into the object
                    fieldInfo.SetValue(ob, value);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        lst.Add(ob);
    }

    return lst;
}

static object GetValue(object ob, Type targetType)
{
    if (targetType == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if (targetType == typeof(String))
    {
        return ob + "";
    }
    else if (targetType == typeof(int))
    {
        int i = 0;
        int.TryParse(ob + "", out i);
        return i;
    }
    else if (targetType == typeof(short))
    {
        short i = 0;
        short.TryParse(ob + "", out i);
        return i;
    }
    else if (targetType == typeof(long))
    {
        long i = 0;
        long.TryParse(ob + "", out i);
        return i;
    }
    else if (targetType == typeof(ushort))
    {
        ushort i = 0;
        ushort.TryParse(ob + "", out i);
        return i;
    }
    else if (targetType == typeof(uint))
    {
        uint i = 0;
        uint.TryParse(ob + "", out i);
        return i;
    }
    else if (targetType == typeof(ulong))
    {
        ulong i = 0;
        ulong.TryParse(ob + "", out i);
        return i;
    }
    else if (targetType == typeof(double))
    {
        double i = 0;
        double.TryParse(ob + "", out i);
        return i;
    }
    else if (targetType == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        // do the parsing here...
    }
    else if (targetType == typeof(bool))
    {
        // do the parsing here...
    }
    else if (targetType == typeof(decimal))
    {
        // do the parsing here...
    }
    else if (targetType == typeof(float))
    {
        // do the parsing here...
    }
    else if (targetType == typeof(byte))
    {
        // do the parsing here...
    }
    else if (targetType == typeof(sbyte))
    {
        // do the parsing here...
    }
    else if........
    ..................

    return ob;
}
```

Comment: This one working Fine .

Comment: DataTable dt1 = SqlHelper.GetTable("select * from employee;");
List<Employee> employees = BindList<Employee>(dt);

Comment: @kselva Months ago, I have asked the same question. Many folks have shared their knowledge to me. And now, it is my turn to pass on the answers to someone else :)

Comment: I tried the extended instance, and it didn't return fields when using `var fields = typeof(T).GetFields();`.  As such, `var fields = typeof(T).GetFields();` may not work for custom classes.
After some digging, I discovered to use `var fields = typeof(T).GetRuntimeFields();`  _My solution doesn't fit in one comment, so the next comment is the solution._

Comment: With `typeof(T).GetRuntimeFields()` you will get field names like: **<EmpName>k__BackingField**, of which does not match up with `fieldInfo.Name == dc.ColumnName` where dc.ColumnName is "EmpName".  Instead, you'll need to convert each dc.ColumnName to match the fieldInfo.Name.  I use a string template of `string fnTemplate = "<{0}>k__BackingField";` then use `tFN = string.Format(fnTemplate, dc.ColumnName).ToLower();` and then compare as `if (fieldInfo.Name.ToLower() == tFN)`.

Comment: what is dont know the binding type `T` can we get a generic list without specifying type?

Comment: @transformer If you don't bind it with a type 'T', then how does the system know what Fields of Properties that the type 'T' has?

Comment: thats the challenge i am facing, since the incoming files are from different sources and schema is not defined

Comment: @transformer you can, by passing an object of your CLASS. Then you can get the type dynamically using myClassObject.GetType().

Answer (score 3):

using LinQ you can do ,

```
  List<DataRow> list = Datatablle.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Updated answer .Create Helper class to Convert Datatable to List

```
public static class Helper
{

    public static List<T> ConvertDataTableToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : class, new()
    {
        try
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>();

            foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
            {
                T obj = new T();

                foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(row[prop.Name], propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                list.Add(obj);
            }

            return list;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then,

```
DataTable dtDatatable = GetEmployee();
List<Employee> employeeList = dtDatatable.ConvertDataTableToList<Employee>();
```

Comment: i need to assign DataTable Values Directly to this List

Comment: List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

Comment: Kindly check updated answer.

Comment: yes yes i will update the answer , just now i am applying into my code

Comment: i got error in this line dtDatatable.ConvertDataTableToList<Employee>();

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
List<Employee> listObject = dTable.AsEnumerable()
                                  .Select(x => new Employee()
                                  {
                                    EmpId = x.Field<int>("EmpId"),
                                    EmpName = x.Field<string>("EmpName"),
                                    EmpAddress = x.Field<string>("EmpName"),
                                    EmpPhone = x.Field<string>("EmpPhone"),
                                    Status = x.Field<bool>("Status"),
                                    EmpRelationKey = x.Field<int>("EmpRelationKey")
                                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: _"but i don't want to mention column names"_

Comment: Use its column index instead

Comment: Yeah, @sujithkarivelil, using column index is also not dynamic, which is what kselva is seeking...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, whenever you make any changes in `DataTable` structure then those changes must be done in `Class` also and if your changing `Class` then sync those changes with `DataTable` structure.

```
List<Employee>employees = new List<Employee>();  

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)  
{  
    Employee emp= new Employee();

    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Employee).GetProperties();
    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
    {
        property.SetValue(emp, Convert.ChangeType(row[i], property.GetType()));
    }
}
```

don't forget `using System.Reflection;`

Comment: keep in mind that if you change column name or property of your class - this code will produce incorrect result

Comment: what is stands for that property.setValue , error occur in that line

Comment: 's' is capital not small. And what is the error