C# Bind Posgres Json B result
I have below query returning some json result in postgres
select t.transaction_id,
  jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('title', t.title, 'created_date', t.created_date, 'created_by', t.created_by))
  AS content
  from temp_table group by t.transaction_id

I have below c# code
public class MainClauseHistoryDto
{
     [JsonProperty("transaction_id")]
     public int TransactionId { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("content")]
     public List<NegotiatedContent> NegotiatedContents { get; set; }
 }

 public class NegotiatedContent
 {
     [JsonProperty("created_by")]
     public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("created_date")]
     public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("title")]
     public string Title{ get; set; }
 }

I would like to bind above json to NegotiatedContent. In my DataAccess layer i am calling stored procedure and returning above data as DataTable.
//below code to query db and return dataset.
    var result = await _negotiationRepository.GetMainClauseHistoryAsync(IndicationRequestId, ParagraphId);
    var mainClauseHistory = result.Tables["main_clause_history_tbl"].ToModelList<MainClauseHistoryDto>();

Below is ToModelList
public static List<T> ToModelList<T>(this DataTable dt)
{
    if(dt?.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        var seralizeData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(seralizeData)!;
    }
    else
        return new List<T>();
}

In the above code I am getting error
Error converting value \"[{\"created_by\": \"iser1\"

Above error message with whole json is coming, may I know how we can bind json directly to our c# model? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

You can't just expect a deserialised DataTable to serialise to a type of your choice. Look at the value of seralizeData data.

Maybe you should look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38865748/1663001 for an example of how to convert a DataTable to a list of a generic type. However, I don't think you should be using DataTable in the first place, it's a very old technology, and whatever is inside _negotiationRepository.GetMainClauseHistoryAsync already seems to be doing something to your input data.
